# mysqldump file imports slowly compared to phpmyadmin file

Tags: cron, phpmyadmin, backup, mysql

I have a large mySQL database that I backup each night via a cron job:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt USERNAME -e -h SERVERNAME -uUSER -pPASSWORD > /home/DIRECTORY/backup.sql
```

It is working well - except when I go to 'restore' the sql file on another server - it takes a long time (about 3 mins)

This is in contrast to using phpMyAdmin - if I do "export" and export the same mySQL database, then import that sql file into another server it only takes 10 seconds.

**Question:** how do I make "mysqldump" create the same type of sql file that "phpMyAdmin" does?

**Example of some FAST version sql (not all of it):**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `absence_type` (
  `absence_type_ID` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`absence_type_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `absence_type`
--

INSERT INTO `absence_type` (`absence_type_ID`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Sick Leave'),
(2, 'Personal Carers'),
(3, 'Other');
```

**Example of some SLOW version sql (not all of it):**

```
        --
    -- Table structure for table `absence_type`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `absence_type`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `absence_type` (
      `absence_type_ID` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`absence_type_ID`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `absence_type`
    --

    LOCK TABLES `absence_type` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `absence_type` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `absence_type` VALUES
 (1,'Sick Leave'),
 (2,'Personal Carers'),
 (3,'Other');
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `absence_type` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: What are the options you are choosing in PHPMyAdmin - drop table, extended inserts? Make them match and see if you still get the discrepancy in import times.

Comment: thanks @JasonMcCreary - I just choose "quick export" from PHPMyAdmin - there are no options?

Comment: That means you are using the default options. Why don't you compare the two files. I'm sure there is something obvious - file size, `INSERT` statements, etc.

Comment: Thanks @JasonMcCreary - I've had a look - there are some differences. I've editted my original question with some examples. The only problem is I dont know what commands I'm supposed to use to make them the same?

Comment: start with the slow and remove rows thats not in the fast query, you can start with the pair of enable/disable keys, next the pair Lock/Unlock, the drop table, and the 3 character_set_client, and last add `IF NOT EXISTS`, after that they should be equal, witch change made the speed jump?

Comment: thanks @JasonMcCreary - I re-read your original post, and the removal of "extended inserts" from mysqldump (the -e) fixed the issue. Can you please post your answer so I can accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***From my comments…***

Likely the options between `mysqldump` and PHPMyAdmin export don't match. For example, inclusion of `DROP TABLE`, extended `INSERT`, etc.

I suggest comparing the two files. I'm sure there is something obvious. Then either adjust the options for `mysqldump` or in PHPMyAdmin. Either should work as the latter uses `mysqldump` underneath.